React Native 0.74.0 Android builds fail "cannot find symbol import com.facebook.react.fabric.FabricJSIModuleProvider"
After upgrading to RN 0.74.0 the npx react-native run-android fails with the error -
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
/Users/phil/Code/app-name/android/app/src/main/java/com/app-name/app/newarchitecture/MainApplicationReactNativeHost.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
import com.facebook.react.fabric.FabricJSIModuleProvider; ^ symbol: class FabricJSIModuleProvider location: package com.facebook.react.fabric

I've followed the steps in upgrading from 0.7.3.6 to 0.74.0 using the Upgrade Helper. iOS builds are okay but facing this issue with Android builds. I understand this is related to using the New Architecture, however I have newArchEnabled=false setting in gradle.properties.

I had the same problem. Turns out the newarchitecture folder was meant to be deleted when upgrading from 0.70.x to 0.71.x.
See the upgrade helper to see it yourself.
Therefore, deleting the newarchitecture folder is the right thing to do here.

I'm not sure, but try :

clear cache, delete build folder, rebuild

If it still not work :

add this in your proguard-rules.pro
-keep class com.facebook.react.fabric.** { *; }



Thanks, but unfortunately still getting the same error...

So, I managed to work around this by deleting the newarchitecture folder which contained the MainApplicationReactNativeHost.java file (and a few other java files). Since I'm not using the New Architecture in RN (newArchEnabled=false) I figured I don't need these files. I can now build successfully for Android.
